# How Can I get Raty Js Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div tag that is raty . my problem is that i do not know how can i get raty value when the user select the stars .

I tried this code but it does not work for me .

```
 $("#foodQulity").click(function () {
 debugger;
 var score = $('#foodQulity').attr("alt");  
 alert(score);                              
 //save to database                         
 });
```

this html tag

```
  <div class="raty" id="foodQulity">
   </div>
```

And This is my raty Js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.raty').raty({

            starOff: '/content/styles/review/Images/star-off.png',
            starOn: '/content/styles/review/Images/star-on.png'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what stars? what value? There is no `alt` in markup. Please provide full details for your issue.

Comment: Is that all your code? Where is `$("#foodQulity").raty()` ?

Comment: sorry ithought that is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) :

> Click
>
> Callback to handle the score and the click event on click action. You
>   can mension the Raty element (DOM) itself using this.
>
> $('div').raty({   click: function(**score**, evt) {
>       alert('ID: ' + this.id + "\nscore: " + **score** + "\nevent: " + evt);   } });

and

> Functions
>
> $('#star').raty('score'); Get the current score. If there is no score
>   then undefined will be returned.

With your own code, just add what the documentation says :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.raty').raty({
            starOff: '/content/styles/review/Images/star-off.png',
            starOn: '/content/styles/review/Images/star-on.png',
            click: function(score, evt) {
               alert("score: " + score);
            });
    });
</script>
```

If this doesn't work and still throws no alert when you rate, check your console for any errors (have you included jQuery correctly? etc.)

Comment: i tried this , but it does not work . can you show me with my own code . thank you very much @Jeremy Thilie